# NestJS : Inject Service into Models / Entities

Tags: dependency-injection, entity, nestjs

i am currently stuck on a problem, which i don't know how to propery solve:

In my NestJS application, I would like to make all my `TypeORM Entities` extend a `BaseEntity` class that provide some general features. For example, i would like to provide an additional `getHashedID()` method that hashed (and therefore *hides*) the internal ID from my API customers.

Hashing is done by a `HashIdService`, which provides an `encode()` and `decode()` method.

My setup looks like this (removed the Decorators for readability!):

```typescript
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  id: int;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  // ...
}

export class BaseEntity {
  @Inject(HashIdService) private readonly hashids: HashIdService;

  getHashedId() {
    return this.hashids.encode(this.id);
  }
}
```

However, if i call the `this.hashids.encode()` method, it throws an exception with:

```
Cannot read property 'encode' of undefined
```

How can i `inject` a service into a `entity/model` class? Is this even possible?

**UPDATE #1**
In particular, i would like to "inject" the `HashIdService` into my `Entities`. Further, the `Entities` should have a `getHashedId()` method that returns their hashed ID.. As i don't want to do this "over and over again", i would like to "hide" this method in the `BaseEntity` as described above..

My current NestJS version is as follows:

```
Nest version:
+-- @nestjs/common@5.4.0
+-- @nestjs/core@5.4.0
+-- @nestjs/microservices@5.4.0
+-- @nestjs/testing@5.4.0
+-- @nestjs/websockets@5.4.0
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Why is it necessary that this particular service gets injected as opposed to just referencing a utility function?

Comment: @JesseCarter Maybe it needs something like access to DB which is otherwise injected?

Comment: @JesseCarter I just updated my initial question. I would like to inject the `HashIdService` so my entites are able to hash their own ID.. How would you solve this issue? What do you mean with a "utility function"?

Comment: You need to manually set the service, if you want to use it in the model.

Comment: Did you considered extending BaseEntity and then using the extended version?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to inject the `HashIdService` or mock it in a unit test you can simply do this:

BaseEntity.ts

```
import { HashIdService } from './HashIdService.ts';

export class BaseEntity {

    public id: number;

    public get hasedId() : string|null {
        const hashIdService = new HashIdService();
        return this.id ? hashIdService.encode(this.id) : null;
    }
}
```

User.ts

```
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    public email: string;
    public name: string;
    // ...
}
```

Then create your user:

```
const user = new User();
user.id = 1234;
user.name = 'Tony Stark';
user.email = 'tony.stark@avenge.com';

console.log(user.hashedId);
//a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0...
```

Comment: This becomes extremely difficult / impossible if `HashIdService` also has a DI chain.